# Showing that $(e^{iA})^{\dagger} = e^{-i A^{\dagger}} $ for a square matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$. I want to understand why $(e^{iA})^{\dagger} = e^{-i A^{\dagger}}$. By definition:

$(e^{iA})^\dagger = ( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {1} {k!} (iA)^k)^\dagger
= (I+ iA + i^2\frac {1} {2} A^2 + \cdots )^\dagger$, which now I am guessing that
$(I+ iA + \frac {1} {2}i^2 A^2 + \cdots )^\dagger = (I + -iA^\dagger + -\frac {1} {2}i^2 (A^\dagger)^2 \cdots)$. But what does it mean to take the conjugate transpose of a convergent sequence of matrices?

Comment: What do you mean? At no moment you took the conjugate transpose of a convergent sequence of matrices. At each step, you took the conjugate transpose of a (or of some) matrix (or matrices).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I guess I should think of it as just taking the conjugate transpose of the partial sums?

Comment: Your computation began by assuming the formula $e^{iA}=i\sum_k\frac1{k!}A^k$ (and then taking the conjugate transpose of both sides). But that equation is wrong. It should be $e^{iA}=\sum_k\frac1{k!}(iA)^k$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass edited, is that correct now?

Comment: You still need parentheses around $iA$, so that not only $A$ but also $i$ get raised to the $k$-th power.

Comment: @AndreasBlass fixed.

Comment: As @JoséCarlosSantos commented, your question isn't exactly about taking the conjugate transpose of a convergent series. Rather, it is why the conjugate transpose of the sum of a convergent series is obtainable by taking the conjugate transpose of each term individually. The answer to that is that the operation of conjugate transpose is linear (over the reals, so you can handle finite partial sums term by term) and continuous (so you can take the limit of those partial sums). The answer by Kavi Rama Murthy explains the continuity part of the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A_n \to A$ then all the elements of $A_n$ tend to the corresponding elements of $A$ and hence the conjugate transpose of $A_n$ tends to the conjugate transpose of $A$. Apply this to the partial sums of the series.